# Pokemon go egg progress color changes

Tags: pokemon-go

Does anyone know why the hatching progress status for some eggs turns blue of some non incubating eggs, when the Pokemon list sorting is changed? For others it remains black. It seems like sorting the Pokemon list has an affect on the I hatched eggs order, at least sometimes. Has anyone noticed a pattern?

[image] [image]

Comment: sounds like a just little bug to me at first glance

Comment: When did you obtain the egg?  At 21:25 (first picture)?  I'm wondering if the text is blue for when absolutely no progress has been made towards it, and as soon a small unreported amount of progress is made, the number changes to black (or grey, can't really tell what color that is).

Comment: @TimmyJim there is no progress, since neither egg is in an incubator

Comment: @yoozer8 I don't play pokemon go so I was just taking a shot in the dark :)

Comment: If it happens sometimes, it is probably a bug and probably what is meant when an update brings minor text fixes.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/57y3hg/blue_progress_number_on_nonincubated_eggs/) post, this appears to be a bug when your scroll from incubated eggs to non-incubated eggs.

> This only happens when you swipe between the eggs, incubated to unincubated

I have verified this by scrolling through my eggs and the number will stay blue when I scrolled through at least two incubated eggs.

Comment: Interestingly, my game is showing a pattern described in another comment in that thread: I have one egg incubating (say it's #1), and swiping shows eggs #4 and #7 with a blue zero.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie It may vary on number of eggs owned vs. number of eggs incubated, phone model, app version, etc... but it does go to say the scrolling is the common culprit